# Show only numeric keyboard for EditField

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde, virtual-keyboard

I have EditField. I want to show virtual keyboard only with number, without letters. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I'm confused - I can't seem to find the setInputType method in the BB 7.0.0 API? Can you post a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
object.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.NUMERIC));
```

Answer (score 0):

`amount->setInputMode(bb::cascades::TextFieldInputMode::NumbersAndPunctuation);`

You can find all the types here:
https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__textfieldinputmode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either construct the EditField and pass `EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC` as the style: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#FILTER_NUMERIC

OR

You can call `EditField.setFilter()` http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#setFilter(net.rim.device.api.ui.text.TextFilter) and pass in a`TextFilter`. Use the static `TextFilter.get()` function and pass in one of the filter constants from the `TextFilter` class, eg http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/text/TextFilter.html#NUMERIC

Numeric filters accept non-negative integers only (0 - 999999999 and beyond), Integer filter accepts all integers negative, zero and positive, and REAL_NUMERIC accepts any decimal number (negative, zero, positive, with an optional decimal point).